# CSS rotation, final frame and inline-block

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've recently been experimenting with CSS animations and have come across some behaviour I can't explain with regards to final frame state.

Given this very small piece of HTML:

```
<span id="rotateme">This is text</span>
```

Some CSS:

```
#rotateme { display: inline-block; }
.clockwise { 
  animation: clockwise 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.anticlockwise {
  animation: anticlockwise 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes anticlockwise {
  from { transform: rotate(0deg); }  
  to { transform: rotate(-90deg); }
}
@keyframes clockwise {
  from { transform: rotate(-90deg); }  
  to { transform: rotate(0deg); }
}
```

And a little bit of Javascript to tie it together:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  d3.select('#rotateme')
    .on('click', rotateAnticlockwise)

  function rotateClockwise() {
    d3
      .select(this)
        .classed('clockwise', true)
        .classed('anticlockwise', false)
        .on('click', rotateAnticlockwise)
  }

  function rotateAnticlockwise() {
    d3
      .select(this)
        .classed('clockwise', false)
        .classed('anticlockwise', true)
        .on('click', rotateClockwise)
  }
});
```

(For a live example, this is also in a [codepen](http://codepen.io/chooban/details/MwOeRM/))

If you click on the text it'll rotate, click on it again and it'll rotate back. However, if you remove the `display` style from `rotateme` element then the final frame of the animation isn't preserved. For the clockwise motion this means it snaps back to the original, horizontal position, and the anticlockwise motion starts from the wrong place.

My question is, what is that `inline-block` is doing in this situation that makes the animation work as I expect it to. i.e Stay in what I understand to be the forward fill mode.

I should add that I'm doing this in Chrome 43 just in case it's a browser quirk.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: you may be surprised to see how it behaves on display: block :)

Comment: position: absolute seems to solve the problem. Though i don't know why

Comment: @EmreTürkiş Ha! Using block made me laugh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Span elements are inline by default, and therefore have limitations on dimension, position, etc. By removing `inline-block` from the style display, you're allowing it to revert to inline, whereby dimension and position are stripped.

Comment: Ah, okay. Having the changing attributes reset at the end makes sense if that's what happens with inline elements. What's the reason for the rather odd "block" behaviour where the elements drops rather than rotating?

Comment: Block-level elements are full-width by default. Put a background color on it to see it better. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdVxMg

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much for such a speedy answer.